# Dynamically inject webpack react bundle into a running page

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-bundle

I have a react webpack bundled page wrapper that looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|               HEADER              |
+-----------------------------------+
|                                   |
|                                   |
|              CONTENT              |
|                                   |
|                                   |
+-----------------------------------+
|               FOOTER              |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I would like to inject another bundle, let's call it page 1, into the CONTENT area, and would like it to be able to interact with some global instances I have that can interact with the footer and update its content.

---

I was successful in downloading the page 1 bundle, and was successful injecting it into the content area.. but the bundle is isolated and cannot reach (or I don't know how) the instances from the first bundle.

How can I make the two bundles communicate?